# Opening my website via the domain name opens up a different website than when opening using IP. No VirtualHosts used

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, curl, networking, dns

#### Raw details

```
Site: blog.helloenglish.com
IP:   107.22.249.42
```

#### Noticing the problem

Started to notice that all google caches, search metadata, webarchive pages, facebook link previews for blog.helloenglish.com have turned japanese.

I could not replicate the issue though. I have an Indian ISP (Airtel broadband) with Google DNS.

Only if I open the website via a US VPN (Tunnelbear, in my case), or use a VPS (EC2 instance in N. Virginia) to curl, I'm able to see the japanese site.

#### The website

Examining the site, it's some weird blog with posts about softwares, screwdrivers (yeah, actual screwdrivers. not even sonic), anchors, pliers, etc. I still have not found what website is this, but in the source it loads resources from [bnote.net](http://bnote.net), which has a similar layout, is in japanese, and has similar posts. But the site I see on [blog.helloenglish.com](http://blog.helloenglish.com) is different from bnote. Bnote behaves like an actual blog, focusing on softwares, each link referring to a post. But most of the links on blog.helloenglish.com are broken, with no `href` tags.

Opening any page on the domain opens up a different post in the japanese site. Examples:

- http://blog.helloenglish.com/robots.txt
- http://blog.helloenglish.com/manifest.xml
- http://blog.helloenglish.com/helloworld
- http://blog.helloenglish.com/foobar

Some screenshots [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMtuE.jpg).

#### Some details about the infrastructure

Our setup is based on AWS completely.
The website is deployed using an Elasticbeanstalk application, hosted on EC2 Instances. The EC2 instance has the elastic IP 107.22.249.42. Our DNS Server is Route53 by AWS.
There's an A record there for `blog.helloenglish.com` with the value `107.22.249.42`.
For the purpose of solving this problem, I've also set up an identical record for `blog2.helloenglish.com`. That domain has faced no issue.

The server has no virtual hosts.

#### curl

I'm ssh'ing into the blog's webserver now. I'll post the results from my ISP too.

```
VPS $ nslookup helloenglish.com
Server:     172.16.0.23
Address:    172.16.0.23#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   blog.helloenglish.com
Address: 107.22.249.42


MY_ISP $ nslookup blog.helloenglish.com
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   blog.helloenglish.com
Address: 107.22.249.42
```

The results for my PC and the VPS are the same.

```
Input:

VPS $ curl -v 107.22.249.42 --header 'Host: blog.helloenglish.com'
VPS $ curl -v blog.helloenglish.com

Output for all those commands:

* Rebuilt URL to: 107.22.249.42/
*   Trying 107.22.249.42...
* Connected to 107.22.249.42 (107.22.249.42) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.40.0
> Accept: */*
> Host: blog.helloenglish.com
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Thu, 19 Jan 2017 06:08:17 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
<
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>2013春の新作,ファッション-その他</title>
<meta name="description" content="その他-城東テクノ Joto 高気密型床下点検口 (高断熱型450×600mm) フローリング15mm対応 ナチュラル (1セット) SPF-R45F15-BL2-NL,2013春の新作-ファッション" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="keywords" content="その他,2013春の新作,ファッション,人気blog" />
... (the japanese source)

----

Input:

MY_ISP $ curl -v 107.22.249.42 --header 'Host: blog.helloenglish.com'
MY_ISP $ curl -v blog.helloenglish.com
MY_ISP $ curl -v blog2.helloenglish.com
VPS $ curl -v blog2.helloenglish.com
VPS $ curl -v 107.22.249.42
VPS $ curl -v 107.22.249.42 --header 'Host: foobar'
VPS $ curl -v 127.0.0.1
VPS $ curl -v 127.0.0.1 --header 'Host: blog.helloenglish.com'

Output for all those commands:

* Rebuilt URL to: 107.22.249.42/
*   Trying 107.22.249.42...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 107.22.249.42 (107.22.249.42) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: blog.helloenglish.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Thu, 19 Jan 2017 06:08:02 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Link: <http://blog.helloenglish.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
<
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="ie ie7" lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="ie ie8" lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) & !(IE 8)]><!-->
... (correct source)
```

Sending any other host apart from blog.helloenglish.com serves the correct site. It does make it sound like a vhosts problem, but it doesn't explain why I wouldn't see that on my PC.

It appears to me that it's a bug in how AWS forwards ElasticIPs. If it is, then it's a very serious and scary bug. Because the problem doesn't seem to be with route53, as curling the IP with host header reproduces the bug. curling the private IP of the instance doesn't reproduce it. I have no Idea what this has to do with the request coming from different zones though.

Comment: chack the Virtualhosts on the server side, when using IP in the Host header you'll reach any vhost with this IP in servername or the default vhost if none is defined for this name. Same thing with the blog name, if no virtualhost is defined with a server name matching this Host header you'll get the default virtualhost instead.

Comment: Have no such entry in the vhosts. In fact, the domain blog.helloenglish.com is an ALIAS entry of http://helloenglishblog-env.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com If I curl that url, the desired page (actual page) opens up.

Answer (score 0):

several servers serve a different website, depending on the `Host` header. it's basically what makes "shared hosting" so cheap, you can serve unlimited websites from a single ip/computer, all distinguished by the `Host` header.

try `curl -v 107.22.249.42 --header 'Host: blog.helloenglish.com'` , and you should get the same result

Comment: It's not really a shared host. 107.22.249.42 is the elastic IP to my AWS EC2 instance. Basically, that IP address points to a server I control.

`curl -v 107.22.249.42 --header 'Host: blog.helloenglish.com'` actually did returned the source of bnote.net (when accessing via a VPS), but I'm unable to understand why. The same command returns the source of my website when I run it on my ISP.

Comment: Sending any other host header gives me my site as the result.

Comment: Run a traceroute to the server from your VPS and ISP networks.